# how to add client proxy as provider in my unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

so I'm trying to test a controller and that controller using ClientProxy as injectable , when I'm running my test it will give the error

```
   Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TransactionsController (TransactionsService, ReconciliationsService, ?). Please make sure that the argument micro at index [2] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

the controller

```js
@Controller()
export class TransactionsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly transactionsService: TransactionsService,
    private readonly reconciliationsService: ReconciliationsService,
    @Inject('micro') private micro: ClientProxy,
  ) { }
```

in the test

```js
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [TransactionsController],
            providers: [TransactionsService, {
                provide: TransactionsService, useValue: mockTransactionS
            }, ReconciliationsService, {
                    provide: ReconciliationsService, useValue: mockReconS
                }, ]
        }).compile()
```

any idea how I can add the ClientProxy or mock it here , any help will be much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to overcome this issue so what I did is that in the provide section I just mock the micro service by adding the below

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        controllers: [TransactionsController],
        providers: [TransactionsService, {
            provide: TransactionsService, useValue: mockTransactionS
        }, ReconciliationsService, {
                provide: ReconciliationsService, useValue: mockReconS
            }, { provide: 'micro', useValue: {} },]
    }).compile()
```

if any one have any better solution please do share it